# x windows in a browser. ajaxterm but with X

Tags: ssh, x-windows, cloud, amazon-ec2

ajaxterm is a terminal that works in a web browser

is there a similar solution for x windows?

if i'm in a library or on a netbook i can't use vnc, but every computer has a browser. so is there a way to run X in a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WeirdX](http://www.jcraft.com/weirdx/) might run as a browser applet.  Most Unix VNC servers also have built-in mini web browsers that serve up Java VNC applets; or there's a standalone package downloadable [here](http://danielwebb.us/software/vnc/).

Comment: wow, amazing. I actually didn't expect a solution.

Comment: I vaguely recall SCO's Skunkworks (I think) releasing a proof-of-concept browser applet for this, but this is all I could find on a quick search.

Answer (score 1):

looks like gtk3.2 will allow it with html5 http://vimeo.com/21062117

Answer (score 0):

An X server is *much* more complex than a terminal emulator. That's not to say that it couldn't be done, but it's far more work than "point browser at existing X server".